# Retraining IBM-Watson-cognitive on fly

Tags: ibm-watson

Sometimes Watson replies that he does not understand what I ask him.
Is it possible to teach Watson directly in the conversation?
For example:
Watson knows that the first US President George Washington.
I ask him, "Who was the first US head of state?"
Watson says he does not know the answer.
Then turn on the training mode, and I say: The Head of State is the President.
Then Watson already knows the answer to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built in way to do that.  That is somewhat by design.  Training of your Watson service should always be supervised - some SME should be making sure that you are training your service with the actual truth (see Microsoft's issues with their Tay chatbot for an illustration of why - http://fortune.com/2016/03/24/chat-bot-racism/).

Now I would suggest doing training, but you need to supervise the training.  Your orchestration layer (the program controlling the Watson conversation service) should log and note questions that the service was unable to answer.  You should then pull these logs, and then it is possible to add training questions and intents for those questions.